# Can a javascript file be dynamic (different for each client when he loads) ? How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, cherrypy, mako

Each client on the site has his own composition of HTML elements.  Some may have 3 elements while others may have 123.  There is little if any similarity between the elements.  And each element requires specific code to manipulate the various elements.  In fact each client may need a different JavaScript file after each search or action taken on the site.

So, how can the server supply customized Javascript files on the fly for each session?

I use python/cherrypy/mako on the server side...

TIA

Dennis

Comment: Not really.  It would be wonderful if all problems in the world could be categorized and boxed.  But the reality is that MOST problems in the world are dynamically hairy.  Are you trying to tell me that it is impossible?  I actually can solve the problem with python and MACKO, I just do not know how to convey the JS file across along with the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple JavaScript files and just include the ones you need..

If you really do need every JavaScript file to be dynamically generated, take a look at [inline JavaScript](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Placing_the_Code#Inline_JavaScript):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        some_client_specific_code();
    </script>
</head>
...
```

Comment: The variation is infinite!  The intersection of two elements require modifications of the javascript on the fly.  This is not a hard problem and can be achieved by use of MAKO, I just don't kinow how to pass along a dynamic JS file with the dynamic HTML file... to the client...

Comment: @DennisKean - Maybe the `<script>` tag is what you're looking for then?

Comment: I see that you are getting close to the solution.  Kudos.  Yes, the <script> tag would solve the problem adequately, but that would make my HTML file rather large.  I was trying to get away from that.  I was hoping that one could submit different JS files along with the HTML files in a dependent uniqueness.  You understood the problem.  So I will tilt the hat to you.  Nice cap  too.. @Brendan

Comment: @DennisKean - If the files really have nothing in common with each other, I don't think you really gain anything by having two smaller files vs one big one, you just have twice as much HTTP overhead.

Comment: If there are pieces that can be used (functions), I would put them in a static .js file, and put as little as possible in the HTML though.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I was trying to find out if the dynamics which are extended to the HTML are also available for the JavaScript files.  I know that all programmers work hard at squashing the problems into 2D.  But real problems are really 3D and above.  Dynamic JS files would be a godsend.  Thank you for thinking along with me on this.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should seriously rethink the idea of dynamically-generating JavaScript files that are specific to a particular user of the system. It may sound like a neat idea at first, but it probably points to an underlying design flaw that if corrected could result in a simpler, stabler and more-easily-run system.

Given all that, generating dynamic JavaScript is little or no different than generating dynamic HTML. You have a template file that contains the skeleton of the JavaScript and markup tags that represent the areas where the dynamic parts go. Then, you need to have a URL handler that can respond to requests for the file. Normally, JavaScript files are handled like other static files such as images or CSS, but you'll treat it like a handler for a dynamic HTML file.

The HTML file that you create will have to include the URL for your generated JS file. Let's say, for instance, that you key off of an integer user id. The URL for your main page might be something like `http://myapp.com/home/11234`, where 11234 is the id for the specific user. Inside the template for that page, you'd have to have a `script` tag that has an href that points to the URL for the dynamially-generated JavaScript file, something like `http://myapp.com/js/11234`.

Finally, the URL for the dynamic JavaScript file will have to contain an Id component that the handler can use to load whatever data is required to make the file specific for the given user.

Again, I do not recommend this technique.

Comment: The clients have nothing in common with one another.  Their needs vary as far and wide as the pegasus galaxy is from the milky way.  In fact I can solve the problem with python and MAKO very easily.  I just do no know how to submit both files (JS and HTML) to the client at the same time.  This is not a monumental difficulty.  I just do not know the solution.

Comment: I understand your advice and you are right if the solution was client dependent.  But I should have mentioned that the same client might take actions and alter the requirements and then require a different JS file adapted to the new request.  The problem itself is the focus, not the client or the site objective.  Can you see that?

Comment: By the way, Adam, thank you for thinking along with me on this.  I was hoping that Python/cherrypy/Mako as a set were able to convey unique JavaScript files just as they do with HTML files.  I mean every client can get a custom tailored HTML dependent on the data in a DB.  Why can we not do the same with JS files?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the process of generating the HTML and the JS files is important enough to have them both generated at the same time. And regenerating the JS file after the HTML file is sent could be problematic.

In that case, you can always cache the JS file and generate a token for it and refetch it from the HTML file?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/fetch/my/${token}">
</head>
...
```

This will regenerate a second request to the server, and you can have CherryPy (sorry, not familiar with it) call a process and simply return the content of the ${token} with the correct http headers... and delete the file from disk.

Is this a viable solution instead of to regenerate the JS suggested by @Adam Crossland.

Comment: By the way @Danosaure, this is feasible when JS code is encoded in the HTML header or body.  Therefore, even though most people are nay saying this, I use it all the time with Python and MAKO, effectively.  And I do not see a problem with doing this.  I understand that it is hard to wrap the head around this issue, but it is quite useful and immensely powerful.  So, it would be dandy if, like HTML, the server could customize a desired JS file on the fly to accommodate different clients.

Comment: I am just trying to add to answers from others, and trying to help out with the part where you mention `I just do no know how to submit both files (JS and HTML) to the client at the same time.`. I don't believe it's possible that HTTP request return two responses on a single call. This is what I understand from what you wish to do. The server can accomoddate different clients, but you need to tell him how.